# node.js socket.io script getting killed by SIGSEGV after 1-2 days

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, segmentation-fault

I am running my node.js server by forever and my script gets killed in 1-2 days and i get this error in the log file:

```
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGSEGV
```

Now i have many functions in my node.js script. Upon writing a console.log at  the beginning of each function i ended up getting this in the log:

```
info: transport end (undefined)
debug: set close timeout for client CbU1mvlYaIvDWHB4ChQa
debug: cleared close timeout for client CbU1mvlYaIvDWHB4ChQa
disconnection function
debug: discarding transport
debug: clearing poll timeout
debug: client authorized
info: handshake authorized 2O3m1B3dGWFOJ4W9ChQc
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGSEGV
```

the log makes it seem as if either the connect or the disconnect function has a problem, but as the script seg faults after 2 days of running and over 10000 connections/disconnections i think that that might not be really the problem.

Here are my connection and disconnection functions. i also connect to my pgsql database via node-dbi:

```
var DBWrapper = require('node-dbi').DBWrapper; 
var DBExpr = require('node-dbi').DBExpr; 
var dbConnectionConfig = { host: 'localhost', user: 'user', password:   'pass', database: 'dbname' };
dbWrapper = new DBWrapper( "pg", dbConnectionConfig );
dbWrapper.connect();

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {


  console.log("socket connection");

socket.on('set username', function(userName) {
var milliseconds = (new Date).getTime();
var data = { socketid: socket.id, time: milliseconds };
dbWrapper.insert('all_sockets', data , function(err) {
});

});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {

  console.log("disconnection function");
  dbWrapper.remove('all_sockets', [['socketid=?', socket.id]] , function(err) {} );
 });

});
```

where could the segment fault be coming from?

Comment: Are you using any compiled addons? `find node_modules/ -name \*.node` should show results if you are. Did you get coredump (e.g. node.core) in the directory of the main entry script?

Comment: the find command gives me this:
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build/Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build/Release/obj.target/validation.node
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build/Release/bufferutil.node
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build/Release/validation.node
node_modules/pg/build/Release/obj.target/binding.node
node_modules/pg/build/Release/binding.node
i dont get a .core filein the directory of the script

Comment: any help? i got another error today after 2 days

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a segfault handler to determine the STDERR. This way you will have some more useful debug info.

[You can find one here](https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler)

Comment: how can i get this on a remote server?

Comment: You can install packages with npm. Try: npm install segfault-handler

Comment: unable to install it. get error
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
gyp ERR! stack     at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:66:16)

Comment: Use a stable node version (v0.10.28 currently)